# How can I check if a contract has self-destructed in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, dapp-development

I have got a problem: I have a contract factory that creates some temporary contracts. I want every contract to exist for about 5 days, afterwards, it self-destructs. However, I want to create a directory that stores the addresses of all temporary contracts and lists them for you. Registering the temporary contracts to the directory contract is no problem I just don't know how I can find out if a contract does still exist so that the destroyed contracts are not listed anymore.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to find a Solidity way to determine whether a contract has already self-destructed?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I want

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After a contract has called `selfdestruct()`, all values are set to `0`. So if you have a contract like:

```
contract Mortal {
    address public owner;

    function Mortal() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function kill() {
        selfdestruct(owner);
    }
```

Then from another contract you can call:

```
function checkMortal(address mortal) {
    if (Mortal(mortal).owner() == 0) {
        // You know it is dead.
    } else {
        // You know it is alive.
    }
}
```

Update:

In newer versions of Solidity that target byzantium or later, this will likely fail. Solidity now verifies returndatasize to know if the call failed, so when `owner()` doesn't return anything, not even 0, it will revert the transaction. The best way to do this now is probably to use extcodesize within [solidity assembly](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.7/assembly.html). This will only tell you it selfdestructed if you know it previously had a non-zero codesize.

Comment: Mortal takes no parameters...how is `Mortal(mortal)` possible then?

Comment: `Mortal(mortal)` is not a constructor, it is an instantiation of `Mortal` at address `mortal`.

Comment: The instantiation calls the constructor for `Mortal`. The constructor takes no parameters, however, so how can `Mortal(mortal)` not throw an error?

Comment: For the enlightenment of passersby:  it's not actually a constructor.  See [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17896/how-is-this-code-feasibly-valid) for the full explanation.

Comment: @JossieCalderon If anything, it's more like a cast than a constructor.

Comment: @Xavier Leprêtre B9lab, Sorry Xavier, you said "this will likely fail", I don't know what you mean by "this"? If you talk about "selfdestruct", it doesn't fail, kindly see my post in 2022:https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/92585/selfdestruct-why-am-i-able-to-execute-the-function-containing-selfdestruct/92613#92613

Comment: In the question you linked you talk about `selfdestruct`. The fail I am talking about is about `.owner()`. This `.owner()` call will fail.

Answer (score 3):

Calling method owner() on an non-existing contract should fail (throw an exception) - not return 0 as suggested.

You can call if something has been deployed at a given address using:

```
function contractExists(address contract) public view returns (bool) {
    uint size;
    assembly {
        size := extcodesize(contract)
    }
    return size > 0;
}
```