# How is this code feasibly valid?

Tags: go-ethereum

is this code valid? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/8484/10138
I just don't see how Mortal(mortal) - an instantiation of the Mortal contract with one parameter - is possible **when Mortal takes no parameters**!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see why you're confused.  **The key thing to know here is that `typename(X)` *looks* the same as `functionname(parametername)` but is actually a totally different operation you may well be familiar with, *casting*.**

For those who don't know, casting is about changing the type of a variable, usually from a simpler type to a more complex type that typically inherits from it.  For example, you may want to cast a uint32 to the larger-but-still-compatible uint64 type.  To do that, you preface the *name* of the variable you want to cast with the name of the type you want to cast it to, and then surround it with parentheses like this:

`uint64(mycurrentvariablewhichisauint32)`

In the case of your question, we are specifically looking at a lesser known feature of the Solidity language: **contracts all inherit from the "address" type, and therefore address types can be casted to contract types**.

Given this information, it's easy to see what's going on in the snippet you reference.  As Badr points out, **the confusingly named *address* "mortal" is assumed by the snippet to be the address of an *already instantiated copy* of a mortal type contract** (or technically mortal-interface-compatible since it doesn't have to be exactly mortal it just has to include the function signatures mortal includes, usually because it inherited from it).  However, in order to actually *call* one of the mortal functions you have to tell solidity that this particular address is a contract of type mortal.  You do that by casting the address to the mortal type:

`Mortal(theaddressofthecontractwhichisactuallyamortaltypecontract)`

This is **not** a call to the constructor for Mortal, which would look like `new Mortal()` and would generate its own brand new address from scratch.  Make sense?

Comment: So, basically, we're downcasting an address to `mortal`: kind of like an `Object` to `String` (in Java)?

Comment: Yup!  I always feel like the terms upcasting and downcasting should be reversed but since it is going from a base class to a derived class it would indeed be a downcast.

Comment: @JeffColeman I'm curious why you think the terminology for upcasting and downcasting should be reversed? When I see "down" I think "lower-level" so it makes sense to me, you're casting to something more specific. Upcasting is higher-level and in general will always be guaranteed to work (assuming the interface is implemented correctly), whereas downcasting requires that you know the underlying type ahead of time.

Answer (score 3):

you mean this snippet code :

```
function checkMortal(address mortal) {
    if (Mortal(mortal).owner() == 0) {
        // You know it is dead.
    } else {
        // You know it is alive.
    }
}
```

the Mortal(mortal) in this case is an instantiation of the Mortal contract, it is similar to

```
function checkMortal(address mortal) {

Mortal M=Mortal(mortal);
        if (M.owner() == 0) {
            // You know it is dead.
        } else {
            // You know it is alive.
        }
    }
```

Comment: **Yes, but why can it be instantiated?** There's no constructor for Mortal with one parameter, which is called when an instantiation of the Mortal contract (with one parameter) is created.

I can see `Mortal M=Mortal()` being valid, but not `Mortal M=Mortal(someParameter)`.

Comment: forget the POO vision, here the constructor is a function executed once when the contract is created. so when you call it using its address its mean that you are not calling its constructor.

Comment: What's POO stand for? And is there a name for this pattern that you are talking about (`Contract(Address)`)?

Comment: @JossieCalderon that is not the code that is doing the instantiating.  What Badr means is that the function has been passed the address of an *already instantiated* copy of mortal.  The code `Mortal(passedInAddress)` is simply casting the address type to a "Mortal" type so that one of its functions can be called.  Now that I wrote that out, I think it probably deserves a whole separate answer, so I'll write one.

Comment: Poo or OOP for oriented object programing,